# Speeding up for loops, maybe using a generator?

Tags: python, performance, iterator, generator

I'm fairly new to python, and I have a problem where I am trying to count how many solutions there are to an equation, such as Ta + Nb + Mc +Pd =e where e is inputted. I don't care what the solutions are, just the quantity.

Abcd are variable positive integers and NMPT are fixed integers

I know it's a rookie error, but I tried 4 nested for loops and it took far too long so I abandoned that, but couldn't think of a more elegant way. Even when I eliminated potential numbers from being allowed the loops I still ended up with a larger computing time.

I have read about generators taking vastly less time but I am unsure how to use them properly, I managed to get the time down to a minute or two but want it quicker using a function with yield in.

Something like, not exactly this but to this extent, and yes I know nesting loops is unfavourable, but Im a novice and trying to learn.

```
def function():
    count = 0 
    for a is in range (0,e)
        for b is in range (0,int(e/N))
            Another for loop 
                Another for loop
                    count += 1
    yield count
```

And outputting that, it gave me quicker results but not quick enough.

Or am I thinking about this in entirely the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: This is an incorrect application of `yield`. You would typically employ it in a place where you will be returning scores of values, not just one. `yield` facilitates lazy evaluation, and your function actually returns a generator that yields a single value - count.

Comment: Generators optimize for memory usage, not speed.

Comment: "I have read about generators taking vastly less time" - unfortunately, they don't. Relative to list comprehensions, they take less memory, and you can stop them early if you don't need all elements, but relative to the loops you're already using, they may even be slower.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the question is here.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to speed-up nested for-loops in to use [*itertools.product()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all of parameter values and [*itertools.starmap()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) to apply the parameters to a function:

Instead of:

```
for a in range(5):
    for b in range(8):
        for c in range(10, 17):
            for d in range(5, 11):
                 v = f(a, b, c, d)
                 ...
```

Write this instead:

```
for v in starmap(f, product(range(5), range(8), range(10,17), range(5,11))):
    ...
```

The benefits are:

- More concise functional style
- The integer values are created just once
- You don't constantly rebuild the same integer lists
- Only one tuple is allocated by *product()* and it is reused
- Both *starmap()* and *product()* run at C speed (no pure python steps)
- The function "f" is only looked up once.

Answer (score 0):

This is a class of problem where a better algorithm will yield far superior performance gains than changing how the code works.

So the problem you have is, given `T`, `N`, `M`, `P`, and `e` find how many solutions there are.

Now something like `yield` would work for the case where you need all the solutions... getting all the solutions is going to involve enumerating all the solutions, which is going to be 4 nested loops... `yield` could help for that case.

Counting solutions allows us to find tricks to reduce how much we need to walk...

So let's start with the outermost loop

```
for a in range(1, ?)
```

How high can the range go? well we know that for a solution to be valid all of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` must be positive, i.e. `>= 1` so we could have the highest `a` value if `T*a + N*1 + M*1 + P*1 == e`... hence the upper bound for `a` is `int((e - N - M - P) / T)`

```
for a in range(1, int((e - N - M - P) / T))
  for b in range(1, ?)
```

How high can the range for `b` go? Well we know that we have `T*a` already...

```
for a in range(1, int((e - N - M - P) / T))
  for b in range(1, int((e - T*a - M - P) / N))
    for c in range(1, ?)
```

How high can the range for `c` go? Same principle...

```
for a in range(1, int((e - N - M - P) / T))
  for b in range(1, int((e - T*a - M - P) / N))
    for c in range(1, int((e - T*a - N*b - P) / M))
      ?
```

Now at this point you might be tempted to do *another* for loop... but here is where we need to be smart, avoid the last loop if we can... because the upper limit of the range is actually the count of valid solutions!

```
count = 0
for a in range(1, int((e - N - M - P) / T))
  for b in range(1, int((e - T*a - M - P) / N))
    for c in range(1, int((e - T*a - N*b - P) / M))
      count = count + int((e - T*a - N*b - M*c) / P)
```

That is a superior algorithm, as it has fewer loops and will consequently return faster...

Oh but there is more... if you know mathematics, and if I recall correctly you can certainly remove another loop, if not remove all of them... but this is where you need to actually know mathematics rather than just brute-forcing the solution

Comment: Thank you! Rmoving that extra loop would be extremely handy. Also, forgot to mention that abcd can be 0. I do know mathematics but unfortunately you can't really do anything without another equation to optimise it. I am also not entirely sure how the final line works?